# Spinner OnTouchListener

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am trying to set `OnTouchListner` on `spinner`. Able to call it on customized view but not able to call on spinner.

Also tried using `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`. Code not working on `Spinner` but
working on CustomView-

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    pos=finalI;
                    Log.e("In View CLicked", "Clicked " + finalI);
                    loadVisitData();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Code not working on Spinner-

```
spinDist.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Log.e("Touch","OnTouch");
                }
                Toast.makeText ( EnquiryForm.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                Log.e("Touch","OnTouch");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for `Spinner` by override `setOnTouchListener()` method,

```
spinDist.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    Toast.makeText ( EnquiryForm.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
              }
              return false;
          }
   });
```

Comment: still not working after using MotionEvent.ACTION_UP. Also tried putting spinner in linearlayout to avoid dispachevents on root view.